# Simulate signin/login using Symfony/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: security, authentication, symfony1, doctrine

In a situation, where the user is authenticated on another application (like oAuth or a custom security implementation), how can we simulate login?

What we intend to achieve is:
- use the user identifier key to check if the user exists
- if the user exists, set-up the session for the user
- basically, setup the attribute holder
- assign the user object, so that it is available thru getUser() method
So we are looking at signing-in programatically!

Any light on how do it in the simplest way?

Comment: Are you trying to create a single sign-on system? If yes, search google for SSO symfony.

Comment: yep, kind of, but more towards oAuth, instead of LDAP or NTLM. but more in line with by-passing the guard plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using sfDoctrineGuardPlugin, i'd do something like:

1. Redirect user to 3rd part oAuth provider
2. On success, user returns to you, either create them a new sfGuardUser object, or retrieve the appropriate one (you may need to adapt the schema to have somewhere to store extra oAuth data).
3. Call myUser()->signIn($user), where $user in the previously retrieved sfGuardUser object - eg: I use this in register actions to log people in after registration: $this->getUser()->signin($user);

Comment: cool.. can't wait to try this! i hope the signin method is implemented in the base class! will let you know.. thanks a ton!